# How do I force a hit in my second-level cache in my JUnit test?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, ehcache, second-level-cache

I’m using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final with the accompanying ehcache module.  I want to verify in a JUnit (v 4.11) test that my second level cache is configured properly but I don’t know how to force such a situation.  I have a simple method for retrieving an entity by its id, which is

```
public T findById(final Serializable id)
{
    T ret = null;
    if (id != null)
    {
        ret = (T) m_entityManager.find(persistentClass, id);
    }   // if
    return ret;
}
```

And then in n my JUnit test I have this

```
@Test
public void testSecondLevelCache()
{
    long hitCount = m_cache.getStatistics().getCacheHits();

    final String countryId = m_testProps.getProperty("test.country.id");
    m_countryDao.findById(countryId);
    m_countryDao.findById(countryId);
```

However the second call hits Hiberntae’s first-level cache and repeated calls to the DAO method will also hit Hibernate’s first level cache.  How do I force a hit into the second level cache?

**Edit:** Below is how the transaction manager and other relevant sections are configured in my Spring application context ...

```
<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager"
class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache"/>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"
p:shared="true" />

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.mainco.subco.core.jpa.SubcoMysql5Dialect" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
    <entry key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" />
</util:map>

<bean id="sharedEntityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: How is your transaction management in this situation?

Comment: I have edited my question to include my Spring application context configuration, which includes the reference to the transaction manager.

Comment: Where does the transaction start and stop in your code example? From what I understand the 1st level cache is bound to a transaction, while the 2nd level is kept between transactions, so what you need to do is get the same entity several times in different transactions, and check that you get the same object back each time. If possible, also that no queries are executed.

Comment: The "findById" is marked as @Transactional, I forgot to include that in the code above but will edit my question soon.  Can you provide a code example in an answer so I can try what you're suggesting?  As I have it, I'm already getting the same entity back from different transactions.

Comment: Ok, and no `@Transactional` on the tests? What parts of your configuration do you want to test? Since you are already testing that the caching works..

Comment: Again, I'm not understanding what you're saying, a code example would be gold.  Marking the test as @Transactional means the transaction is never committed until after the test is over, so how does one test a hit against the second-level cache?  My code above only tests the first level but my question is how can I write Java code to test the second level.

Comment: If your test is not `@Transactional` you are in fact testing the 2nd level cache. Hard to come up with code examples when I don't know exactly what you want to test ("test the second level cache" is just way to broad..) But the answer below shows you one way, you won't need the transactionTemplate-stuff though, since you have `@Transactional` on your findById-method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to remove the `@Transactional` annotation from the test or class level so that you control transactions manually.

Second, you need to change the test to use two consecutive transactions with two `EntityManager` instances.

```
@Test
public void testSecondLevelCache() {
    long hitCount = m_cache.getStatistics().getCacheHits();       
    final String countryId = m_testProps.getProperty("test.country.id");

    transactionTemplate.execute((TransactionCallback<Void>) transactionStatus -> {            
        m_countryDao.findById(countryId);
        return null;
    });

    transactionTemplate.execute((TransactionCallback<Void>) transactionStatus -> {
        m_countryDao.findById(countryId);
        return null;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not getting any results from "m_cache.getStatistics().getCacheHits()" after the two calls, but perhaps my ehcache is not configured properly.  My question is, does putting the calls in a transaction template always by-pass the first-level cache?  I'm using the "org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate" template.

Comment: You cannot bypass the 1st level cache. This solution will use two `Session` instances so you can visualize the number of SQL queries generated to fetch the `Country` entity. If there is one SQL query, then the 2nd level cache is configured properly.

Comment: Oh I see so the first call to "findById" hits the database, and then the second call, since it belongs to a different session, would hit the second level cache instead of the database (assuming my second level cache is configured correctly).  Is that the rationale?

Comment: That's right. The second session should use the 2nd level cache